# How to unhide an Eclipse working set?

Tags: eclipse

How do I unhide a working set in Eclipse?

I'm using Eclipse and I'm trying to organize my projects into working sets. When I was deleting one of my working set folders (by pressing the delete key on the working set), two options appeared: remove or hide. I clicked on hide but now I want to unhide this folder - how can I do that?

Comment: are you talking about an eclipse working set?

Comment: Yes eclipse working set.

Comment: So, this sounds like it's not really a java question so much as an eclipse question where you happen to be dealing with java files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you were in the Package or Project Explorer view when you pressed delete.

Click the small down arrow (3 vertical dots in newer versions of Eclipse) at the top right of the view to show the view menu.

In `Package Explorer` select `Configure Working Sets` to show a dialog which will let you re-enable the working set. In `Project Explorer` the option is `Select Working Set`.